# How to upload all files from a certain folder and store them as variables

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, file-upload, load

I have a folder that contains several files, which I want to upload and store as variables.

```
from spacepy import pycdf


data14 = pycdf.CDF(r'C:\Users\nikos.000\psp_data\fields\l2\mar_rtn_r\psp_fld_l2_mag_RTN_2020060300_v01.cdf')
data15 = pycdf.CDF(r'C:\Users\nikos.000\psp_data\fields\l2\mar_rtn_r\psp_fld_l2_mag_RTN_2020060306_v01.cdf')
data16 = pycdf.CDF(r'C:\Users\nikos.000\psp_data\fields\l2\mar_rtn_r\psp_fld_l2_mag_RTN_2020060312_v01.cdf')
data17 = pycdf.CDF(r'C:\Users\nikos.000\psp_data\fields\l2\mar_rtn_r\psp_fld_l2_mag_RTN_2020060318_v01.cdf')
data18 = pycdf.CDF(r'C:\Users\nikos.000\psp_data\fields\l2\mar_rtn_r\psp_fld_l2_mag_RTN_2020060400_v01.cdf')
data19 = pycdf.CDF(r'C:\Users\nikos.000\psp_data\fields\l2\mar_rtn_r\psp_fld_l2_mag_RTN_2020060406_v01.cdf')
data090 = pycdf.CDF(r'C:\Users\nikos.000\psp_data\fields\l2\mar_rtn_r\psp_fld_l2_mag_RTN_2020060412_v01.cdf')

testB=np.concatenate((data14['epoch_mag_RTN'][:],
                     data15['epoch_mag_RTN'][:],
                     data16['epoch_mag_RTN'][:],
                     data17['epoch_mag_RTN'][:],
                     data18['epoch_mag_RTN'][:],
                     data19['epoch_mag_RTN'][:],
                    data090['epoch_mag_RTN'][:]))
```

I want to store the path of each file to a list

```
file_names = [] # a list where each element is the name of each of the files
                # for example the first should be r'C:\Users\nikos.000\psp_data\fields\l2\mar_rtn_r\psp_fld_l2_mag_RTN_2020060300_v01.cdf'
```

And then use a for loop

```
for i in range(len(list)):
    data14 = pycdf.CDF(list[i])
    testB=np.concatenate((testB,
                          data14['epoch_mag_RTN'][:]))
```

Comment: You can use `glob` Try: `file_names = glob.glob('*.cdf')` This will give you all the files that end with `'.cdf'` in your current directory.

Comment: @It_is_Chris Thanks for your comment however I coulld not understand where the path of the folder should go

Comment: It goes in the first param: `file_names = glob.glob(r'C:\Users\nikos.000\psp_data\fields\l2\mar_rtn_r\*.cdf')`